# image slider multiple rows with just css or angularjs?

Tags: css, angularjs, image

Is there a way to create an multiple row image slider like the one in the image below using just css?  or is there a way to do this with angular?

The slider needs to move as one (single rows cannot be swiped individually).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand the overflow property in css:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/

This will allow you to see there is a scroll property. That can make your scroll bars. Yours should use overflow-x to scroll the direction you want it to go.

As for angular, you need to look into ng-repeat command. Here is a fiddle that is doing what you are looking for:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | limitTo:display_limit">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/hp4w7/

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer to your question.. `no, there is no way to do this with just CSS` because you will have to handle the swipe, touch, click, etc. events using javascript. I guess I was working under the assumption that you would be adding angularjs into your application solely for this purpose, so I made a jQuery solution. If that is a wrong assumption, I will rewrite an angular solution.

Basically, the idea is that you structure your HTML/CSS in a way to get the effect of the sliding within a given container, and then use event handlers to update the slider as the user interacts with it.

**[Working DEMO](http://jsbin.com/pekapejido/1/edit)**

#### HTML

```
<div class="slider-display centered">
    <div class="image-container">
      <div class="image">Image<br>1</div>
      <div class="image">Image<br>2</div>
      <div class="image">Image<br>3</div>
      <div class="image">Image<br>4</div>
      <div class="image">Image<br>5</div>
      <div class="image">Image<br>6</div>
      <div class="image">Image<br>7</div>
      <div class="image">Image<br>8</div>
      <div class="image">Image<br>9</div>
      <div class="image">Image<br>10</div>
      <div class="image">Image<br>11</div>
      <div class="image">Image<br>12</div>
      <div class="image">Image<br>13</div>
      <div class="image">Image<br>14</div>
      <div class="image">Image<br>15</div>
      <div class="image">Image<br>16</div>
      <div class="image">Image<br>17</div>
      <div class="image">Image<br>18</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="centered" style="text-align: center; max-width: 350px;">
    <button class="move-left"><--</button>
    <button class="move-right">--></button>
</div>
```

#### Javascript

```
$(function () {
  var getWidth = function ($element) {
    var total = 0;

    total += $element.width();
    total += Number($element.css("padding-left").replace("px", ""));
    total += Number($element.css("padding-right").replace("px", ""));
    total += Number($element.css("border-left").split("px")[0]);
    total += Number($element.css("border-right").split("px")[0]);
    total += Number($element.css("margin-left").split("px")[0]);
    total += Number($element.css("margin-right").split("px")[0]);
    return total;
  };
  var sliderPosition = 0;
  var imageWidth = getWidth($(".image").eq(0));
  $(".move-left").on("click.slider", function () {
    var maxVisibleItems = Math.ceil($(".slider-display").width() / imageWidth);
    var maxItemsPerRow = Math.ceil($(".image-container").width() / imageWidth);
    var numRows = Math.ceil($(".image-container .image").length / maxItemsPerRow);
    var maxPosition =  numRows > 1 ? maxVisibleItems - maxItemsPerRow : maxVisibleItems - $(".image-container .image").length;
    if (sliderPosition > (maxPosition)) {
      sliderPosition--;
      var $imageContainer = $(".image-container");
      $(".image-container").animate({
        "margin-left": sliderPosition * imageWidth
      },{
        duration: 200, 
        easing: "linear",
        queue: true,
        start: function () {
          $(".move-left").prop("disabled", true);
        },
        done: function () {
          $(".move-left").prop("disabled", false);
        }
      });
    }
  });
  $(".move-right").on("click.slider", function () {
    if (sliderPosition < 0) {
      sliderPosition++;
      var $imageContainer = $(".image-container");
      $(".image-container").animate({
        "margin-left": sliderPosition * imageWidth
      },{
        duration: 200, 
        easing: "linear",
        queue: true,
        start: function () {
          $(".move-right").prop("disabled", true);
        },
        done: function () {
          $(".move-right").prop("disabled", false);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

#### CSS

```
.image {
  float: left;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background: #888888;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.image-container {
  width: 650px;
  position: relative;
}
.slider-display {
  max-width: 450px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ddd
}
.centered {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```